# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when fetching from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a request to my localhost server but am getting the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Here is my front end code:

```
(async () => {
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/articles/', {
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080/articles/" }
    });

    const articles = await data.json()

    console.log(articles)
})();
```

and backend code:

```
app.get("/articles/", function (req, res) {
    let inputValue = req.body.page;
    let pages = Math.ceil(totalResults / 10)
    page = scripts.iteratePages(inputValue, page, pages);

    request("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=" + initialQ +
        "&category=sports&pageSize=10&page=" + page + "&sortBy=relevance&apiKey=" +
        apiKey, function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                let data = JSON.parse(body);
                let articles = scripts.articlesArr(data);
                res.json({ articles: articles });
            } else {
                res.redirect("/");
                console.log(response.body);
            }
        });
});
```

I've done some research myself, which points to using my private IP address instead of `localhost` and am getting an `... is not a function` error in the console:

```
let ipAddress = "blah.blah.blah.blah"

    (async () => {
        const data = await fetch('http://' + ipAddress + ':8080/articles/', {
            headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://" + ipAddress + ":8080/articles/" }
        });

        const articles = await data.json()

        console.log(articles)
    })();
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Your endpoint is not returning json. Use `res.json({ filtered: articles })` instead of `res.render` and `res.redirect`

Comment: Thanks. But the console is still returning `Uncaught TypeError: "ip address goes here" is not a function`

Comment: What line does code caught error?

Comment: `const data = await fetch('http://' + ipAddress + ':8080/articles/', {`

Comment: If your server is on your machine, `localhost` should work just fine. My guess is that you are using the wrong port. Or that your server did not start (or crashed)

Comment: BTW the __Access-Control-Allow-Origin__ header is a response header, adding it to the request will have no affect.

Comment: I think the issue was that json did not return completely, cause json is required for `fetch`. And if your endpoint is completely returning json (including errors), use `localhost` to do it again.

Comment: @JimmyNeedles have you read my comment above ? Are you sure the server listens on port 8080, and is running *and* listening ? Try a netstat to make sure it is listening correctly.

Comment: @Seblor Hey man, yeah - My localhost was running off of port `3000`, not `8080` - rookie error. It now works. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I think the error was caused by cross domain issues. You make a misunderstanding about CORS headers. The headers are not used by request but response.

If javascript program is making a cross domain request, the browser will first send an OPTION request with same parameters to the server. If backend on the server consider the request is legal, a response with only CORS headers will be send back to the browser, and then the browser check the CORS header against current environment. If CORS headers are suitable, the browser will finaly send the real request to server, or throw an error otherwise.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: The error is a connection refused, not a CORS error. Plus OP is having the issue within the localhost and uses a server. CORS issues only happens in localhost if you are trying to access an http(s) server from a `file://` and it will show a CORS exception, not a connection refused error

Comment: @Seblor you are not that correct with your assumptions, cors - cross-origin resource sharing - does happen on every host, not just `localhost` and is not necessary related to `file://`. I agree with you that the error here is not CORS related.